# Binary fraction in ruby

Tags: ruby, binary

I want to change a floating number to binary form, for example for `12.345`.  I got the integer part done:

```
(12.345).floor.to_s(2) #=> 1100
```

for the fraction, however, can't find the best way to do this.

I do have a way, the way Wikipedia shows [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), but It's a very long process: a while loop with a bunch of temporary variables that I want to avoid. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this it in Ruby.

The full binary form I want to get is `1100.011` in string form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply it with a large-enough power of `2` (say `2 ** 10`), then convert it to binary, and then insert the decimal point back.

```
(12.345 * 2 ** 10).to_i.to_s(2).insert(-(10 + 1), ".")
# => => "1100.0101100001"
```

By the way, I don't think `1100.011` is the correct form.

Comment: you're right, (1.100011) x 2^3 is the appropriate form.  This looks great, thank you for this.